# How to Split string using a regular expression?

Tags: regex, string, express

I want to know How to split string using regex.

e.g

my string is below.

```
String Temp = "/dev/sda        398G  4.9G  373G   2% /mnt/internal";
```

I want to separate the above string to the group name and value .

(Group Name)  =   (Value)

filestream    =   /dev/sda

size = 398G

used = 5.8G

remain = 372G

use% = 2%

mount = /mnt/internal

if anyone know how to convert the above string to regex, please leave answer.

In advance Thanks for your answer.

Everybody have a nice day!

Comment: You can split by spaces `var arr = str.split(/\s+/)`

Comment: `string.split("\\s+")`

Comment: Split with pattern `\\s+` is the straightforward solution, but if you want to go with named group approach, here is an example: http://rubular.com/r/1Vbo3QtUBx

Comment: @NeverHopeless: It is the same approach I used in my C# app to parse `df -h` output :) However, it is JS, and it does not support named captures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no "named groups" in Javascript RegEx afaik.
But you could also do it with "normal" groups. Here is the regex:

```
([\w\d/]+)\s+([\d\.G]+)?\s+([\d\.G]+)?\s+([\d\.G]+)?\s+(\d+%)\s+([\w\d/]+)
```

Details:

```
([\w\d/]+)       -> match group of "chars", "digits" and "/"
\s+              -> followed by at least on whitespace
([\d\.G]+)?      -> match shortest match of "digits", "." and "/" and char "G"
\s+              -> followed by at least on whitespace
([\d\.G]+)?      -> match shortest match of "digits", "." and char "G"
\s+              -> followed by at least on whitespace
([\d\.G]+)?      -> match shortest match of "digits", "." and char "G"
\s+              -> followed by at least on whitespace
(\d+%)           -> match "digits" followed by "%"
\s+              -> followed by at least on whitespace
([\w\d/]+)       -> match group of "digits", "chars" and "/"
```

After that you can access the groups 1 to 6 which correspond to what you need.

http://regexr.com/3bnsd